# How to add function output to string literal in Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. Just putting that out there.

What I want to do is to add the output of a function to a string literal that another function outputs.

This is the case:

**

```
def prime(n):
    **blahh blah blah....**
    if z == True:
        return " and prime"
    else:
        return ""
def happyPrime(n):
     **more blah blah blah**
            if n == 1:
                print ("Number is happy%s!" % prime)
                break
            if n in visited:
                print ("Number is sad%s!" % prime)
            visited.add(n)
```

[Ignore the indentations in the code snippet, StackOverflow made them come out wrong.]
The intended result is, of course, that where the modulo is it adds what the other function returned. I think I may be approaching it the wrong way, though.

Comment: You should use `prime(n)` instead of just `prime`; `print ("Number is happy%s!" % prime(n))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
def happyPrime(n):
     **more blah blah blah**
            if n == 1:
                print ("Number is happy%s!"  %  prime(n))
                break
            if n in visited:
                print ("Number is happy%s!"  %  prime(n))
            visited.add(n)
```

Your `prime(n)` function returns a string. So, `%s` will be replaced with the returned string.

**Alternatively**, you can just concatenate the returned string. For example :

```
>>> def foo(n):
        if n == True:
            return "yay"
        else:
            return "boo"

>>> def happyPrime(n):
        print "bar " + foo(n)

>>> happyPrime(True)
bar yay

>>> happyPrime(False)
bar boo
```

Comment: It's worth noting the Python docs recommend the newer [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) over the old `%` string formatting.

Comment: @Lattyware Thank you for pointing that out. I should have read the Python docs more carefully.

Comment: @ThanakronTandavas It's not a huge problem - `%` style formatting isn't even deprecated yet (although that might happen at some point), but it's probably a good idea to get into the habit of using the new style formatting. It's more powerful and easier to read.

Comment: @Lattyware Couldn't agree with you more. I will stick to [str.format()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) then.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure quite what you mean, if you want %s to return the result of prime(n) you have to give prime an argument because it expects one. from the looks of it, either True or False.

`print ("number is happy%s!" % prime(True))`